# what's the best software to remote control winodws server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-access

I have a windows server 2012 with his own AD domain. I have to manage it from remote, what free software would u advice me ?
between me and the server there are 2 firewall with nat.
I don't want logmein because I have more pc than limit it permits to manage.
Thank you very much.

Comment: The "best" software is the one that meets your needs. You need to assess your options and make an educated decision as the local system administrator. I strongly suggest starting with the built-in tools (PowerShell, Remote Desktop) before looking at other options. If your environment presents problems with a particular piece of software it may be better to ask how you can modify your environment to allow what you need...

Answer (score 1):

Remote Desktop if you can port forward to the server - otherwise Teamviewer is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

windows remobe powershell and/or rsat tools on the management computer and vpn into the server (Server Manager is probably all you need to run on the remote)